# Access to wordpress method inside of classes

Tags: plugins, functions

How could I access an usually word-press method as example $this->get_current_site(); inside of a class?

Answer (score 0):

`get_current_site()` is a (globally accessible) function (located in `ms-functions.php`), it's not a class method, so simply call it it by its name like you would do with any other function.

```
$currentSite = get_current_site();
```

Comment: hi thanks for your feedback I have been trying that than I get Call to undefined function get_current_site()

Comment: Well, you must make sure that the file where it's located is actually included. Normally it's included automatically (in case the site is actually a multisite) via `wp-settings.php` which in turn gets included by the default `wp-config.php`. So either you aren't including `wp-settings.php`, your site is not a multisite, you are calling the function before `ms-functions.php` gets included, or you are using an old WordPress version where this functionality doesn't exist at all.